# How to get only a backend rocket.chat instance

Tags: rocket.chat

Is there any way to get only a backend rocket.chat proyect?
I don't want to use the frontend from rocket. I want to create some app and do some request to the rocket backend to interact with all the server features in rocket.

Answer (score 3):

Its currently not possible.

Rocket.Chat is built using the Meteor framework.  Unfortunately with meteor this is no way to disable the browser platform as a target. [See this ticket for more details](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6091)

It doesn't hurt to have the UI there and just not use it though.

If you are wanting to prevent UI access.  I would maybe look at adding rules to your reverse proxy to return 404 for things such as:

- index.html
- theme.css
- *.js